# How to recode values condition upon value from another filed in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

**DATA**

```
demo <- structure(list(Performance = c("Performance-3", "Performance-2", 
"Performance-2", "Performance-1", "Performance-7", "Performance-8", 
"Performance-4", "Performance-1", "Performance-1", "Performance-1", 
"Performance-2", "Performance-1", "Performance-7", "Performance-2", 
"Performance-1", "Performance-2", "Performance-3", "Performance-4", 
"Performance-8", "Performance-9", "Performance-8", "Performance-1", 
"Performance-7", "Performance-3", "Performance-2", "Performance-3", 
"Performance-4", "Performance-9", "Performance-3", "Performance-8", 
"Performance-2", "Performance-8", "Performance-2", "Performance-7", 
"Performance-3", "Performance-3", "Performance-3", "Performance-7", 
"Performance-7", "Performance-4", "Performance-2", "Performance-2", 
"Performance-2", "Performance-1", "Performance-2", "Performance-4", 
"Performance-1", "Performance-2", "Performance-7", "Performance-4"
), ItemValue = c(4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L)), row.names = c(3583L, 479L, 634L, 
578L, 3759L, 3496L, 9595L, 4052L, 7984L, 5228L, 131L, 1014L, 
4836L, 3912L, 298L, 10027L, 258L, 79L, 6449L, 7526L, 2744L, 4403L, 
902L, 3808L, 561L, 3385L, 4232L, 7962L, 9361L, 959L, 2171L, 5896L, 
1258L, 8800L, 4591L, 4630L, 9347L, 2902L, 9738L, 9143L, 3990L, 
10488L, 9581L, 10905L, 9859L, 8787L, 8626L, 6901L, 760L, 3290L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to reverse the values for Performance-7 such that `5` become `1` ... `1` become `5`

I did this using `ifelse` the following way:

```
demo %>% mutate(ItemValue = ifelse(Performance == "Performance-7" & ItemValue == 5, 1, 
                                             ifelse(Performance == "Performance-7" & ItemValue == 4, 2, 
                                                     ifelse(Performance == "Performance-7" & ItemValue == 3, 3, 
                                                             ifelse(Performance == "Performance-7" & ItemValue == 2, 4, 
                                                                     ifelse(Performance == "Performance-7" & ItemValue == 1, 5, ItemValue))))))
```

But as you can see, there's a lot of `ifelse`. I tried using recode, but couldn't figure out with conditional to another field.

Comment: Have a look at `?recode` and `case_when()`.

Comment: If they are just numbers you could do something like `ItemValue =ifelse(Performance == "Performance-7", 6 - ItemValue, ItemValue)`

Comment: My mind is blown!!! My gosh, what a simple and elegant solution!! All that time I spent writing ifelse ... tsk tsk tsk.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just do a translation:

```
@library(tidyverse)
   demo2 <- demo %>% 
      left_join(transl <- tibble(ItemValue = 1:5, NewItemValue = 5:1),
                by = "ItemValue")
```

Take a look

```
head(demo2)
Performance      ItemValue  NewItemValue
1 Performance-3         4            2
2 Performance-2         5            1
3 Performance-2         3            3
4 Performance-1         5            1
5 Performance-7         2            4
6 Performance-8         1            5
```

Clean it up

```
answer <- demo2 %>% 
  mutate(ItemValue = ifelse(Performance == "Performance-7",
                            NewItemValue, ItemValue)) %>% 
  select(Performance, ItemValue)

head(answer)
    Performance ItemValue
1 Performance-3         4
2 Performance-2         5
3 Performance-2         3
4 Performance-1         5
5 Performance-7         4
6 Performance-8         1
```

Comment: interesting solution, but this recodes every ItemValue. I only want to recode if the Performance == Performance-7

Comment: Yes. it looks better. I think @dpmcsuss had a more elegant solution - just one line.